# SDL Contextual Image Delivery not generating the cropped Image

Tags: sdl-tridion, context-engine, contextual-image-delivery, sdl-mobile

I have followed SDL documentation for SDL Contextual Image Delivery and have done the below steps.

1. [Installing the API Server Role as a .NET Web application](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-0D330E1A-A753-45D2-B462-3121F756EE14)
2. [Installing the Image Transformation Handler in a .NET Web application](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Contextual%20Image%20Delivery-v1/GUID-E96E6D96-7893-4FBB-8425-0D4BD681C492)
3. Installing Context Engine Cartridge

I have provided `img` element in the page as follows

```
<img src="mywebsite.com/cid/scale/100/source/http://myImageWebsite.com/Images/someImage.jpg">
```

I also tried

```
<img src="mywebsite.com/cid/scale/100/source/source/Image/someImage.jpg">
```

when I load the page the folders with path `/cid/scale/100/source/` gets created automatically in my web application but the cropped image is not generated.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Thanks,
Sunil

Comment: Your second URL looks very odd indeed (with two /source/'s and no *s* in \Image\. Have you confirmed you can get the images without any transformations first? ... e.g ``<img src="http://mywebsite.com/cid/mywebsite.com/Images/someImage.jpg">`` or similar? ``<img src="http://mywebsite.com/cid/scale/100/mywebsite.com/Images/someImage.jpg" >`` - **Also** do you see any WARN flags in the CID logs - this should indicate if the URL is not constructed correctly.

Comment: There is no WARN flag in the CID log. also I am not getting the image with `src="http://mywebsite.com/cid/mywebsite.com/Images‌​/someImage.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

In the SDL documentation on [CID](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Contextual%20Image%20Delivery-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-E96E6D96-7893-4FBB-8425-0D4BD681C492&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-E96E6D96-7893-4FBB-8425-0D4BD681C492.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E96E6D96-7893-4FBB-8425-0D4BD681C492), its mentioned that we have to update the web.config as mentioned below

```
<location path="CUSTOM/PATH">
  <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
       <add name="ImageTransformerHandler" verb="*" path="CUSTOM/PATH/*" type="Tridion.Context.Image.Handler.ImageTransformerHandler" />
     </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

where /CUSTOM/PATH refers to the customized URL that you want the image transformer to run against. If you do not want to create a customized URL, omit the path attribute from the location element and set to the path attribute of the add element to *.

If we provide Path=”*” in web.config as shown below, then the log gets generated and nothing happens

```
<handlers>
 <add name="ImageTransformerHandler" verb="*" path=" *" type="Tridion.Context.Image.Handler.ImageTransformerHandler"  />
</handlers>
```

If we provide Path=” http://mywebsite/*” in web.config as shown below, then the log will not be generated but the folders structure (\cid\trim\100\source) get created automatically in mywebsite.com

```
<handlers>
 <add name="ImageTransformerHandler" verb="*" path=" http://mywebsite/*" type="Tridion.Context.Image.Handler.ImageTransformerHandler"  />
</handlers>
```

I am not clear on what exactly we have to provide in the PATH attribute.

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer but more an edit on the original question, can you please delete this answer and **edit** the question to keep the site clean and clear?